# Remove Singly Linked List at nth position

Tags: c++, class, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int d;Node*temp1;
    Node*next;Node*temp2;
};
void insert(Node*&head,int x) 
{
    Node*node = new Node(); // allocate memory 2 node let node be an abstract data
    node->d = x; // define data in the new node as new data (saving data define in there)
    node->next = head; // Let next of the new node as head
    head = node; // let pointer name head point new node
}
void print(Node*node) 
{ 
    while (node != NULL) 
    { 
        cout<<' '<<node->d; 
        node = node->next; 
    } 
}
void Delete(Node*&head,int n) // Delete node at position
{
    int i;Node*node=head;// temp1 points 2(n-1)th
    if(n==1)
    {
        head = node->next; // head now points 2 second node.
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        head = node->next;
    } // temp1 points 2 (n-1)th Node
    Node*nnode= node->next; // nth node temp1=node temp2=nnode
    node-> next = nnode->next; //(n+1)th Node
    
}
int main()
{
    Node*head = NULL; // Start with empty List
    int a,n,i,x;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        insert(*&head,x);  
    }
    cout<<"Enter a position:";
    cin>>a;
    Delete(head,a);print(head);
}
```

The Output is:

```
3 // how many number that singly linked list can received
1 2 3 // define many numbers
Enter a position : 1
2 1 // false output it should be 2 3
```

The output should be:

```
3
1 2 3
Enter a position : 1
Linked List is 1->2->3
position 1 is remove // at any position we want 2 remove it will show that position we remove
2->3  
Enter a position : 4
No data at 4th position
Linked List is 2->3
```

Comment: `*&head` is exactly equal to `head`.

Comment: What are your limitations? Are you allowed to use smart pointers?

Comment: by the way, after you type `1 2 3` the linked list is `3->2->1` not `1->2->3`

Answer (score 2):

In the `Delete` function you have the loop

```
for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
{
    head = node->next;
}
```

Because you pass `head` by reference, you actively destroy the list with this loop. Furthermore since you have `node = head` earlier, the assignment is effectively `head = head->next` in the first iteration.

You need to use the variable `node` instead of `head`:

```
for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
{
    node = node->next;
}
```

---

You also need to protect against going beyond the end of the list:

```
for(i = 0; (i < n - 2) && (node->next != nullptr) ;i++)
```

Comment: it said nullptr not declared in this scope how can i declare nullptr i should use Null and the output is this 3 (number of limits)  1 2 3 Enter a position : 1 then i got 3 2 1 it's not 2 3

Comment: @Lizzar_00 Then you have a *very* old C++ compiler, use `0` instead.

Comment: Well Actually When i had a test or do a c++ assignment the university let me use dev-c so it's not surprised for u if it's 2 old or my code is 2 old lol

Comment: I have a question the professor want me 2 remove the position that not define in singly linked list and have 2 sent out the message no data at that position and show the remaining after remove the nth position i start with 1

Answer (score 0):

For starters the declaration of the node of a singly linked list has redundant data members `temp1` and `temp2` that do not make sense.

The declarations can look like

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
```

In this case the function `insert` (that you could call like

```
insert(head,x);
```

instead of

```
insert(*&head,x);
```

as you are doing) will look like

```
void insert( Node * &head, int x )
{
    head = new Node { x, head };
}
```

In C++ (and in C) indices start from 0. So the function `delete` also shall accept indices starting from 0. The type of the corresponding parameter shall be an unsigned integer type for example `size_t`. Otherwise the user can pass a negative number as an index.

The function produces memory leaks because it in fact does not free allocated nodes. It can invoke undefined behavior when the pointer to the head node is equal to NULL. And in general the function does not make sense.

It can be defined the following way

```
bool Delete( Node * &head, size_t n )
{
    Node **current = &head;

    while ( *current && n-- )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    bool success = *current != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void insert( Node * &head, int x )
{
    head = new Node { x, head };
}

bool Delete( Node * &head, size_t n )
{
    Node **current = &head;

    while ( *current && n-- )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    bool success = *current != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

std::ostream & print( Node * &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( Node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << " -> ";
    }
    
    return os << "null";
}

int main() 
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    
    for ( int i = 3; i != 0; i-- ) insert( head, i );
    
    print( head ) << '\n';
    
    size_t pos = 0;

    if ( Delete( head, pos ) )
    {
        print( head ) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No data at the position " << pos << '\n';
    }
    
    pos = 4;
    
    if ( Delete( head, pos ) )
    {
        print( head ) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No data at the position " << pos << '\n';
    }
    
    pos = 1;
    
    if ( Delete( head, pos ) )
    {
        print( head ) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No data at the position " << pos << '\n';
    }
    
    pos = 0;
    
    if ( Delete( head, pos ) )
    {
        print( head ) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No data at the position " << pos << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
2 -> 3 -> null
No data at the position 4
2 -> null
null
```

Comment: there's a lot of bug when i compile and run

Comment: @Lizzar_00 The shown demonstrative program compiles successfully. There are no bugs.

Comment: @Lizzar_00 Maybe you are using a very old compiler that does not satisfy the C++ 11 Standard . For example try the code at www.ideone.com.

Comment: @Lizzar_00 At www.ideone.com  select the compiler C++ 14.

Comment: OK THANKS WELL THE UNIVERSITY LET ME USE DEV-C FOR THE TEST AND THE ASSIGNMENT I THINK IT'S NO SURPRISED IF I GET A PROBLEM BECAUSE OLD COMPILER

Comment: @Lizzar_00 Are you compiling the program as a C program instead of a C++ program?